# open a xltm file using a batch file, show the comparison results, but how to save in a common path?

Tags: java, excel, batch-file

As per my requirement I've to open a xltm file using a batch file. Xltm file will show the comparison results between 2 excel files. As per my code I've opened the xltm file but I'm not able to save the xltm file in a common path.Anyone please help me on this?

```
public class Execute_Batch_and_Save_Excel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start filepath/Batchname.bat");
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.print("Comparison result XLTM file is opened");
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone please help me on this?

Comment: ChDir "Directory Path"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\FilePath\Filename.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChDir "Directory Path" Application.DisplayAlerts = False ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\FilePath\Filename.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False